# Python Flask not accepting spaces in the variable arguments

Tags: python-2.7, rest, api, flask

I have to call a Python Flask API, and pass variable arguments to the API.
Below is my API route :

```
@app.route('/v2/products/category', methods = ['GET'])
def get_price_dif():
    page = request.args.get('page') 
    category = request.args.get('category')
```

Below is how I call the API with the arguments :

```
localhost:5000/v2/products/category?page=1&category=Mobiles & Accessories
```

The problem here is the API is not accepting the blank spaces in between the words "*Mobiles*", "*&*" and "*Accessories*" in the string "*Mobiles & Accessories*"

If I print the 'category' value received by the API, it shows only "*Mobiles*"

How do I call the API along with spaces in the category value?

Answer (score 2):

I think the space is not required when defining keyword arguments
change your code to the code below. Remove white between methods argument and the ['GET'] array

```
@app.route('/v2/products/category', methods=['GET'])
def get_price_dif():
    page = request.args.get('page') 
    category = request.args.get('category')
```

Try replacing the spaces with %20 and see whether it will work

```
localhost:5000/v2/products/category?page=1&category=Mobiles%20&%20Accessories
```

Comment: I didnot get what you meant by "Remove white between methods argument and the ['GET'] array"?? I tried replaceing spaces with %20...didnt work :( any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I partially solved the problem.

```
category = str(request.args.get('category'))
```

This now allows me to pass arguments containing empty spaces.

```
localhost:5000/v2/products/category?page=1&category=Large Appliances
```

The above call works fine :

```
category : Large Appliances
```

But the problem now arises when my argument contains an ampersand symbol. It is taken as a variable value argument by Flask :

```
localhost:5000/v2/products/category?page=1&category=Home & Kitchen
```

Here category gets truncated as :

```
category : Home
```

How do i by pass the ampersand symbol so that it is also accepted in teh URL?